# What's equal this:$\int_{0}^{\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\cot^{-1}(x^k+\frac{1}{x^k})}dx$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, products

Evaluation for some integer $k$ using [wolfram alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28++arccot%28x%2B1%2Fx%29arccot%28x%C2%B2%2B1%2Fx%C2%B2%29arccot%28x%5E3%2B1%2Fx%5E3%29%29%2C+x%3D0+to+infty)  show that this integral

$\int_{0}^{n}\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\cot^{-1}(x^k+\frac{1}{x^k})}dx$ converges fast and deacreasing to $0$ , Now my question here is :

> > **Question:**  What is the exact value of that integral if it is always converges for any integer $k$ ?

**Note:** I have edited the question because i meant the partial sum product not infinit product because infinit product here is :$0$

Comment: The infinite product is zero for every $x$, so the integral is the integral of 0, which is zero.  Did you mean something different?

Comment: Could u show me how it is 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean

$$\int_0^\infty\prod_{k=0}^n \cot^{-1}(x^k+x^{-k})$$

If $n=0$, it is the integral of a constant $\cot^{-1}2$, so it's infinite.
If $n=1$, the arccot is close to the reciprocal.  So
$$\int\cot^{-1}(x+1/x)dx\approx\int\frac1{x+1/x}dx\\
=\frac12\ln(x^2+1)|_0^\infty$$
which is infinite again.
If $n>1$, I doubt it has an 'exact' value.  Again approximating the arccot by the reciprocal; and then approximating that reciprocal by $x^n$ when $x<1$ and $x^{-1}$ when $x>1$, 
$$\int_0^1\prod x^kdx+\int_1^\infty\prod x^{-k}dx\\=\int_0^1x^{n(n+1)/2}dx+\int_1^\infty x^{-n(n+1)/2}dx=\frac4{n(n+1)}$$
However, a more important effect is that $\cot^{-1}(x^k+x^{-k})$ never gets above $\cot^{-1}2\approx 0.464$, so each new factor reduces the final answer by that factor.

My back-of-the-envelope calculation is that it looks like $$\frac{0.464^n}{n^2}$$

Comment: Thank's , i have edited my question, i meant partial product not infinit because infinit product gives 0